# Silex - My REST POST/PUT calls aren't receiving parameters

Tags: rest, symfony, post, curl, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using the Doctrine DBAL version 2.5 inside of Silex 1.3 to make REST calls to MySQL DB. I manage to get my GET / GET/{id} and DELETE/{id} working fairly easily but I can't seem to get my POST/PUT to work.

Here is the fallowing code

```
$app->post('/student', function($firstName, $lastName) use($app) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_students (firstName, lastName)
            VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)";
    $student = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
    $student->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $student->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $student->execute();

    return "insert successful";
});

$app->put('/student/{id}', function($id, $firstName, $lastName) use($app){
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_students 
            SET firstName = :firstName, lastName = :lastName 
            WHERE id = :id";
    $student = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
    $student->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $student->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $student->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $student->execute();

    return "student succesfully updated";
});
```

If I hard code default values, it works perfectly fine as well as using bindParam() and using my own values.

I keep getting this error message after my curl dumps everything back at me

```
<span class="exception_message">Controller &quot;Closure&quot; requires that you provide a value for the &quot;$firstName&quot; argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).</span>
```

Here are the fallowing curl commands I have used

```
curl -X POST -d "firstName=First123&lastName=Last456" URL/student
curl -X POST -d '{"firstName":"First123","lastName":"Last456"}' URL/student --header "Content-Type:application/json"
curl -X POST -d "firstName=First123&lastName=Last456" URL/student --header "Content-Type:text/html"
```

Comment: `firstName` and `lastName` are not part of your route - hence why you receive that error message. You have to read these either from `Request` or include them in your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silex will not automatically create parameters for your methods corresponding to your post variables. You have to get them from the request object as @Artamiel suggested.

See http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#example-post-route.

The updated code for your post operation should be like this:

```
$app->post('/student', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $firstName = $request->get('firstName');
    $lastName = $request->get('lastName');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_students (firstName, lastName)
            VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)";
    $student = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
    $student->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $student->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $student->execute();

    return "insert successful";
});
```